# Getting error when assigning JSON array value to variable

Tags: json, swift

I would like to assign a value from JSON to a variable, the issue is Swift thinks I am passing an entire array and not just the JSON value of `code` to the variable.

**I have the following structure and JSON decode function:**

```
private func JSONFunction() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example"),
        let nameValue = stringValue.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "name=\(nameValue)".data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }


        do {
            let myData = try JSONDecoder().decode(codeStruct.self, from:data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                codeNum = myData.code
                print(codeNum)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

**The following is the structure for decoding the JSON:**

```
struct codeStruct: Codable {
    let code: String
    let line: String
    let person: String
    let maker: String

}
```

**Error received:**

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription:
>   "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array
>   instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Hi Jamie, what does your incoming JSON look like?

Comment: Without looking at the json, if I were to guess, I would say that your incoming JSON is actually an array of `codeStruct` objects, for which you should change your line to `let myData = try JSONDecoder().decode([codeStruct].self, from:data)`

Comment: My apologies I just noticed the results do actually contain [ ] making it an array, I tried what you said above but now `codeNum = myData.code` gives me the error `Value of type '[codeStruct]' has no member 'code'`

Comment: Please share the incoming JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the json, if I were to guess, I would say that your incoming JSON is actually an array of codeStruct objects, for which you should change your line to

```
let myData = try JSONDecoder().decode([codeStruct].self, from:data)
```